# Eclipse 4.4 apparently using stuff from 3.8

Tags: java, eclipse

when I start eclipse 4.4 (Ubuntu 14.04) I get an error that is stored in a dir:

org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261_linux_gtk_x86_64

which indicates that it is still running stuff from version 3.8.

What am I doing wrong?

the log file contains:

```
!SESSION 2014-10-01 09:48:11.227 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.7.0_65
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-10-01 09:48:12.176
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-10-01 09:48:12.176
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.pde.ua.core_1.0.100.v20110516.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.pde.ua.core 2 0 2014-10-01 09:48:12.176
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.pde.core_[3.3.0,4.0.0).

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-10-01 09:48:12.177
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-10-01 09:48:12.177
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.pde.ua.core_1.0.100.v20110516 [804] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.pde.ua.core 2 0 2014-10-01 09:48:12.177
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.pde.core_[3.3.0,4.0.0).

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-10-01 09:48:12.178
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.getSplashShell(WorkbenchPlugin.java:1326)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4387)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4247)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.createHandle(Shell.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.createWidget(Widget.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createWidget(Control.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.createWidget(Scrollable.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.createWidget(Decorations.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Shell.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.internal_new(Shell.java:386)
    ... 19 more
Root exception:
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4387)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4247)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.createHandle(Shell.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.createWidget(Widget.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createWidget(Control.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.createWidget(Scrollable.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.createWidget(Decorations.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Shell.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.internal_new(Shell.java:386)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.getSplashShell(WorkbenchPlugin.java:1326)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it isn't quite easy to give you an exact explanation for this error message. I'm fairly sure it isn't a problem with plugin versions (3.8 vs 4.4).

The stack trace looks as if somewhere in your Eclipse install there are resources leaking, namely `SWT` resources (might be fonts, images, widgets). Seems like the provider of the respective code hasn't followed the *If you created it, you dispose it* rule laid out in [Managing Operating System Resources](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/swt-design-2/swt-design-2.html).

Yet more unfortunately it isn't trivial to track down that code. You could try deactivating single plugins from your install and check if the error persists. Also try if putting out of use any secondary screens you might use helps. If you can find the rogue code or source of the error, please consider filing a bug report over at [the Eclipse bug tracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/).